# Killing Application.ontime with Workbook_BeforeClose

Tags: vba, excel

I looked through every topic I've found in here, but couldn't figure what is wrong with the below.

I am using Application.OnTime to run a Module every minutes. The problem is, when I close the worksheet, Excel reopens the sheet the next time the Macro should run.

I have attempted to use the following fix, to no avail.

```
Option Explicit
Dim dTime As Date

Public Function AutoRun2()
dTime = Now + TimeValue("00:01:00")
Application.OnTime dTime, "AutoClear"
End Function

Sub StopAutoRun2()
Application.OnTime dTime, "AutoRun2", , False
End Sub
```

and I have the following in ThisWorkbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Call StopAutoRun
Call StopAutoRun2
End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `"AutoRun2"` to `"AutoClear"` in your stop sub as this is the actual macro that you want to stop being scheduled with the `False` argument.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer!

I've done so and the document still opens itself. Mind that I have another script that uses the Application.OnTime to run, but I also call it in the manner as the above, and made changes for both.
I have a StopAutoRun and StopAutoRun2

Comment: Your code doesn't open anything so not sure what you mean? On a side note, this line `If .Cells(i, 4).Value Like "Done" And .Cells(i, 5).Value = "1" > Then` makes no sense - there's not need to use the `Like` operator and there's a `>` after the 1 at the end?

Comment: That's where I get confused too :P The document keeps opening itself once it is closed. So I guess that the Application.Ontime isn't successfully killed. 
The > at the end is a copy-paste mistake. My apologies. 
I also removed the Like and changed it for =. Result is the same though, it did work with the Like :)

Comment: Should I provide you with the other script that has an autorun based on Application.OnTime?
Although that one is more character heavy. Maybe there's only one of the two that fails to False?

Comment: It might help to see the other script too

Comment: Marking this as Answered. It should do it. But it still doesn't so I'll have to follow another path. Your answer is still true that that was a part of the problem.

Comment: Your beforeclose routine contains two calls, one to StopAutoRun and one to StopAutoRun2. You only show the code belonging to StopAutoRun2. What does StopAutoRun contain?